# std::map<Custom, int>::find() does not find anything

Tags: c++, stdmap

For some reason `std::map` does not find my objects.

Here is my simplified object :

```
class LangueISO3 {
public:
    enum {
        SIZE_ISO3 = 3
    };

    static constexpr char DEF_LANG[SIZE_ISO3] = {'-','-','-'};

    constexpr LangueISO3():code() {
        for(size_t i(0); i < SIZE_ISO3; i++){
            code[i] = DEF_LANG[i];
        }
    };
    LangueISO3(const std::string& s) {strncpy(code, s.c_str(), 3);};

    bool operator==(const LangueISO3& lg) const { return strncmp(code, lg.code, 3) == 0;};
    bool operator<(const LangueISO3& lg)const { return code < lg.code;};

private:
    char code[SIZE_ISO3];
};
```

My test is :

```
{
    CPPUNIT_ASSERT_EQUAL(LangueISO3("eng"), LangueISO3("eng"));

    std::map<LangueISO3, int> lmap;
    lmap.emplace(LangueISO3("fra"), 0);
    lmap.emplace(LangueISO3("deu"), 1);
    lmap.emplace(LangueISO3("eng"), 2);
    auto it = lmap.find(LangueISO3("deu"));
    CPPUNIT_ASSERT_EQUAL(1, it->second);
}
```

The first test has no problem, however the second fails. `lmap.find()` always return `lmap.end()`

What did I do wrong ?

Comment: Have you using the debugger to place breakpoints in your comparison functions?

Comment: I did not thinh the problem was comming from the comparaison function so I've overlooked it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't compare character arrays with the `<` operator.  When you write `code < lg.code`, the compiler will compare the *address* of the `code` array, and not the contents of the arrays.

Change the definition for `operator<` to use `strncmp`:

```
bool operator<(const LangueISO3& lg)const {
    return strncmp(code, lg.code, SIZE_ISO3) < 0;
}
```

Also, the comparison for `operator==` should use the `SIZE_ISO3` constant instead of hardcoding the size at `3`.

Comment: Thanks. I wrote that too fast